# Security in ASP.NET Webservice that allow only specific people to use it

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, web-services

I made a webservice in asp.net and I can see that anyone can use it if they know the url.
How can i make it private so no one can use it except for specific people?

Note: I'm trying to use it from my iPhone, it's a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use soap custom header to get user name and password from user

[Authenticate .NET Web Service with Custom SOAP Header](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/SOAPHeaderAuthentication.aspx)